# A clock implemented using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, html5, timer

This is a POC for a clock using moment.js, eventually I plan to recreate this in Raect.js. Any opimisations or a better way to do it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Html clock</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.5/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<p id='show_time'></p>
<p id='show_date'></p>
<select id='timezone_list'></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var list = moment.tz.names();
        var timezone;
        var sel = document.getElementById('timezone_list');
        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = list[i];
            opt.value = list[i];
            sel.appendChild(opt);
        }

        sel.onchange = function(){
            timezone=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
            console.log(timezone)
            setInterval(function(){
                var times = moment().tz(timezone).format('h:mm:ss a');
                var dates = moment().tz(timezone).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
                var par = document.getElementById('show_time');
                var par2 = document.getElementById('show_date');
                par.innerHTML= times;
                par2.innerHTML=dates;
            },1000);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I have created a function to prevent the one second delay.
- Added `moment().tz(timezone)` as variable
- Added all elements as variable
- Added the date and time directly to the elements
- Added a shorter way to add `options`

```js
var list = moment.tz.names();
var timezone;

// elements
var elTimezoneList = document.getElementById('timezone_list');
var elTime = document.getElementById('show_time');
var elDate = document.getElementById('show_date');

// loop over timezones and set options
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   elTimezoneList.appendChild(new Option(list[i], list[i]));
}

// time function to prevent the 1s delay
var setTime = function() {
  var time = moment().tz(timezone);

  // set time in html
  elTime.innerHTML= time.format('h:mm:ss a');

  // set date in html
  elDate.innerHTML = time.format('MMMM Do YYYY');
}

// on change select
elTimezoneList.onchange = function(){
  // set selected timezone
  timezone = elTimezoneList.options[elTimezoneList.selectedIndex].text;

  setTime();
  setInterval(setTime, 1000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Html clock</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.5/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="show_time"></p>
    <p id="show_date"></p>
    <select id="timezone_list"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```